# Display Czech characters in graph title

Tags: r

How do I display Czech characters in graph title?

Example:

```
plot(rnorm(100),main="Žluťoučký kůň, úpěnlivě pěl ódy")
```

Results in:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147769/how-to-display-d-in-r-graphs) I have used hex codes instead of writing text directly.

For example to get `Žluťoučký` you have to write:

`paste("\u017D","lu","\u0165","ou","\u010D","ký",sep="")`

List of Czech characters and their hex codes (taken from Wikipedia)

```
znak    hex
Á   U+00C1
Č   U+010C
Ď   U+010E
É   U+00C9
Ě   U+011A
Í   U+00CD
Ň   U+0147
Ó   U+00D3
Ř   U+0158
Š   U+0160
Ť   U+0164
Ú   U+00DA
Ů   U+016E
Ý   U+00DD
Ž   U+017D
á   U+00E1
č   U+010D
ď   U+010F
é   U+00E9
ě   U+011B
í   U+00ED
ň   U+0148
ó   U+00F3
ř   U+0159
š   U+0161
ť   U+0165
ú   U+00FA
ů   U+016F
ý   U+00FD
ž   U+017E
```